# rows to column transformation in python

Tags: python

i have a csv file like this:

AVG_TP90
11

10

6

6

AVG_TP65    AVG_TP80    AVG_TP90

20              25       31

16              19       28

12              14       16

11              13       16

USED_GB

14453

14045

13964

13753

the output should be:

AVG_TP90    11  10  6   6
AVG_TP65    20  16  12  11
AVG_TP80    25  19  14  13
AVG_TP90    31  28  16  16
USED_GB   14453 14045   13964   13753

How can it be done by python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the contents, find out the dimensions and then transpose:

```
with open("x.txt", "r") as infile:
    # Read line by line and split by space already 
    x = [[k for k in j.split()] for j in [i.strip("\n") for i in infile if i != "\n"]]
cols, rows = max([len(i) for i in x]), len(x) # Get dimensions
output = []
# Transpose, swap rows and columns
for i in range(cols):
    for j in range(rows):
        try:
            output.append(x[j][i])
        except IndexError:
            pass
# Construct the desired output string
retstr = ""
for i in output:
    retstr += i+" "
print(retstr)
```